# Understanding express nodeJs router behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

This route works fine:

```
router.post('/addlog', multipartMiddleware, function(req,res){
   controller.postLog(req,res);
});
```

but if I change the call like this:

```
router.post('/addlog', multipartMiddleware, controller.postLog(req,res));
```

node complains about `ReferenceError: req is not defined`. The controlles is in a separate file:

```
exports.postLog = function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).send('OK');
}
```

why?

Comment: `controller.postLog(req,res)` means call the function immediately. `function(req,res){
   controller.postLog(req,res);
}` means **call**_me_**back**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `controller.postLog` immediately and passing the result of that call to `router.post`.

Assuming you don't need to access `this` as `controller` inside `postLog`:

```
router.post('/addlog', multipartMiddleware, controller.postLog);
```

This passes a reference to the `postLog` function to `router.post` which is what that function expects - it needs a reference to a function so it can invoke that function with a request and response object.

If you need `this` inside `postLog` to refer to `controller` you could use `bind` to produce a new function that will be invoked in the context of `controller`:

```
router.post('/addlog', multipartMiddleware, controller.postLog.bind(controller));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the router behavior, below is article about callbacks in JS.

http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/